# CBLoader : Character sheet has skills like fishing, farming, and actor. How do I remove them?

Tags: dnd-4e, tools

I'm using a 3rd party program called CBLoader (think WotC Character Builder). I created a character in it, choosing its skills and feats etc. I then attempted to create a printable version of the sheet by pressing "Character Sheet", but there is a problem. Under the skills table I have some weird/new skills such as actor, apothecary, architect, cartographer that I would like to get rid of as they will not be used in my campaign or style of play.

**So, can someone please tell me how can I remove those skills from the character sheet created by the program?**

Comment: The version of CBLoader I'm familiar with was used to add 3rd party content to the WOTC offline character builder. My guess would be that you have a third party library that you need to remove

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly and I'm sorry for the late reply, however the library is huge, so I was wondering if anyone knew the exact "campaign" that introduced these skills. Or if anyone had a problem like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all non-stock entries by running the cleanup utility.

Or you can go in and surgically remove them from the `*.part` files that the program reads, which are standard xml files.